# how to add types for vue plugin?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I try add self plugin for vue with type script.

But at moment when i use my method from vue prototype, my method `$auth` does not exist on type myComponent. I also add .d.ts for plugin, but i think he is little not correct, and also i think in plugin don't need use install, or need? Just in some examples i dont see install, but in docs say - need use install.

**my plugin**

```
import _Vue from 'vue';
import store from '@/store'
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export default {
    install: (Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: any) => {
        const base = firebase.initializeApp(config);
        const auth = firebase.auth();
        Vue.prototype.$auth = {
            login: async (username: string, pass: string) => {
                return await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, pass)
            },
            logout: async () => {
                await auth.signOut()
            }
        };
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((user: any) => {
            store.commit('updateUser',{ user })
        })
    }
}
```

**myPlugin.d.ts**

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        $auth: {
            login: (username: string, pass: string) => Promise<any>
        };
    }
}
```

**component**

```
export default class SignUp extends Vue {
    email: string = '';
    password: string = '';

    async onSubmit(){
        if ((this.$refs.form as any).validate()) {
            const auth = await this.$auth.login(this.email, this.password)
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 7):

1. `install` function is a strict requirement, this function is used by Vue internally in `Vue.use(YourAwesomePlugin)` to load your plugin.
2. I could not make the *declaration file* work as well as you mentioned, but in docs  examples an author put the declaration merging in a file with logic (not in a separate `d.ts`). So if you put content of your `myPlugin.d.ts` to a main plugin file - it will load your interface and `$auth` will exist on `this`.

**TS Docs(see *Module Augmentation* section):** [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

---

### UPDATE

To make `.d.ts` file work you just need to import vue in that file.

**Vue docs:** [Augmenting Types for Use with Plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins)